# Basic jQuery - addClass

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am really new to jQuery, in fact I started to learn it yesterday. I caught up with `addClass()` method since this morning and I couldn't wrap around my head yet. Here I tried to add a class using `addClass` method, but couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong.

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/rxhozhu5/1/)

Comment: take out the `.` like this: `$("div").addClass("tester2");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `$.addClass`, you just need to add the `classname` without period.

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $("div").addClass("tester2");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/rxhozhu5/2/

Comment: No worries. I make such mistakes a lot myself. Lol